# Get list of Fields of an Ant Design Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have an **ant design** form on React.

1. How can I get the whole list of **fields** of a form? (all of them are wrapped by Form.Item)?
2. When I submit a form, is there any way to find out which fields are **changed**(touched) and their value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'

function TempForm({ form }) {
    const submit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        form.validateFields((error, values) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log('error while validating')
            } else if (values) {
               console.log('name: ', values.name, 'email: ', values.email)
             }
        })
     }
return (
<Form onSubmit={submit}>
  <div>
      <Form.Item label="Customer">
        {form.getFieldDecorator('name', {
          initialValue: 'John',
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select a customer!' }],
        })(<Input type="text" placeholder="name" />)}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="Customer Email">
        {form.getFieldDecorator('email', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select a Clinic' }],
        })(<Input type="email" placeholder="customer email" />)}
      </Form.Item>
    </div>
</Form>
 )
 }

export default Form.create()(TempForm)
```

Here we are having a antd-form(import all necessary components) and a on-submit function. You can easily access all you fields as shown. Here values will be a js-object containing key-value pair or you can use form.getFieldValue('name') to access form values.

Comment: Thanks, and is there any way to get only touched field pair of key and values? @devSpartan

Comment: Let's say a user type something in input box and deletes it without saving then I think you should use a check variable for every field which will be set to true if there is any change in input field. Or you can check the length of final values if it is 0 or greater than 0

Comment: ok, thank you. there is no direct function to get touched fields